# Using custome UDF withColumn in a Spark Dataset<Row>; java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Row

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-dataset

I have a JSON file containing many fields. I read the file using spark's Dataset in java.

- Spark version 2.2.0
- java jdk 1.8.0_121

Below is the code.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
              .builder()
              .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
              .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
              .master("local")
              .getOrCreate();

Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json("jsonfile.json");
```

I would like to use withColumn function with a custom UDF to add a new column.

```
UDF1 someudf = new UDF1<Row,String>(){
        public String call(Row fin) throws Exception{
            String some_str = fin.getAs("String");
            return some_str;
        }
    };
spark.udf().register( "some_udf", someudf, DataTypes.StringType );
df.withColumn( "procs", callUDF( "some_udf", col("columnx") ) ).show();
```

I get a cast error when I run the above code. 
java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Row

Questions:

1 - Is reading into a dataset of rows the only option? I can convert the df into a df of strings. but I will not be able to select fields.

2 -  Tried but failed to define user defined datatype. I was not able to register the UDF with this custom UDDatatype. do I need user defined datatypes here?

3 - and the main question, how can I cast from String to Row?

Part of the log is copied below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Row
    at Risks.readcsv$1.call(readcsv.java:1)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration$$anonfun$27.apply(UDFRegistration.scala:512)
        ... 16 more

Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$27: (string) => string)
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are getting that exception because `UDF` will execute on column's data type which is not `Row`. Consider we have `Dataset<Row> ds` which has two columns `col1` and `col2` both are String type. Now if we want to convert the value of `col2` to uppercase using `UDF`.

We can register and call `UDF` like below.

```
spark.udf().register("toUpper", toUpper, DataTypes.StringType);
ds.select(col("*"),callUDF("toUpper", col("col2"))).show();
```

Or using `withColumn`

```
ds.withColumn("Upper",callUDF("toUpper", col("col2"))).show();
```

And `UDF` should be like below.

```
private static UDF1 toUpper = new UDF1<String, String>() {
    public String call(final String str) throws Exception {
        return str.toUpperCase();
    }
};
```

Comment: amazing, I need to read docs more carefully. thanks very much

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The UDF doesn't get called at all.

Comment: @abaghel any advice on this UDF issue plz   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63935600/writing-udf-for-looks-up-in-the-map-in-java-giving-unsupported-literal-type-clas

Answer (score 2):

Improving what @abaghel wrote.
If you use the following import

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;
```

Using `withColumn`, code should be as follows:

```
ds.withColumn("Upper",functions.callUDF("toUpper", ds.col("col2"))).show();
```

Comment: How can we callUDF for all columns instead of specific column?

Comment: @Batuhan Tüter any advice on this UDF issue plz   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63935600/writing-udf-for-looks-up-in-the-map-in-java-giving-unsupported-literal-type-clas